# How to combine two dataframes by start time and end time in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can you combine two dataframes, `df1` with expanded time and `df2` with start and end times?

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"time": ["10:34:10", "10:34:20", "10:34:30", "10:34:40", "10:34:50", "10:35:00", "10:35:10", "10:35:20"]})
```

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"start_time": ["10:34:10", "10:34:40"], "end_time": ["10:34:20", "10:34:50"], "session_type": ["11v11", "zonal game"]})
```

The desired output is:

```py
df3

time      start_time  end_time  session_type
10:34:10  10:34:10    10:34:20  "11v11"
10:34:20  10:34:10    10:34:20  "11v11"
10:34:30  NaN         NaN        NaN
10:34:40  10:34:40    10:34:50  "zonal_game"
10:34:50  10:34:40    10:34:50  "zonal_game"
10:35:00  NaN         NaN        NaN
10:35:10  NaN         NaN        NaN
10:35:20  NaN         NaN        NaN
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pandas.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asof.html):

```
df1['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['time'])
df2['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['start_time'])
pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on='time', right_on='start_time')
```

output:

```
                 time          start_time  end_time session_type
0 2021-08-21 10:34:10 2021-08-21 10:34:10  10:34:20        11v11
1 2021-08-21 10:34:20 2021-08-21 10:34:10  10:34:20        11v11
2 2021-08-21 10:34:30 2021-08-21 10:34:30  10:34:40   zonal game
3 2021-08-21 10:34:40 2021-08-21 10:34:30  10:34:40   zonal game
```

Now with your updated dataset, you can use `tolerance`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"time": ["10:34:10", "10:34:20", "10:34:30", "10:34:40", "10:34:50", "10:35:00", "10:35:10", "10:35:20"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"start_time": ["10:34:10", "10:34:40"], "end_time": ["10:34:20", "10:34:50"], "session_type": ["11v11", "zonal game"]})
df1['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['time'])
df2['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['start_time'])
pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on='time', right_on='start_time', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('10s'))
```

output:

```
                 time          start_time  end_time session_type
0 2021-08-22 10:34:10 2021-08-22 10:34:10  10:34:20        11v11
1 2021-08-22 10:34:20 2021-08-22 10:34:10  10:34:20        11v11
2 2021-08-22 10:34:30                 NaT       NaN          NaN
3 2021-08-22 10:34:40 2021-08-22 10:34:40  10:34:50   zonal game
4 2021-08-22 10:34:50 2021-08-22 10:34:40  10:34:50   zonal game
5 2021-08-22 10:35:00                 NaT       NaN          NaN
6 2021-08-22 10:35:10                 NaT       NaN          NaN
7 2021-08-22 10:35:20                 NaT       NaN          NaN
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! If I `df["time"]` has more entries than `df["start_time"]`, is it possible to stop at `df["end_time"]` and fill in-between values with `NaN`.

I have updated the question show the issue.

Comment: I guess you can reindex the output dataframe with df1['time'], I can't check right now, let me know if you don't manage.

Comment: I can't quite solve it as the resulting dataframe fills the `NaN` values and contains the same indices as df1.